# Angular 1.5 and Typescript: best way to prepare to angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, migration

I have an angular 1.5.6 project, using typescript.

In order to prepare to a further migration to angular 2.x, how am I supposed to write controlers/directives/services/filters... as component? Is there a pattern to apply or annotations to use?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS 1.5 contains the notion of a component, which is a central pillar of Angular 2's design. You can have a look at it in the AngularJS documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component.

AngularJS 1.5 and AngularJS 2.0 can be mixed together in the same project. To make this easier, the team is providing a library called ng-upgrade. Find out more at http://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html.

So the idea to go forward now is to build using AngularJS 1.5 (if your code is supposed to go live any time soon) and to use Components where applicable; then migrate your code over to AngularJS 2.0 piece by piece using ng-upgrade.